# Unsupported locale prevents me from starting apps

Tags: 13.04, kubuntu, locale

I have the following locale settings when I type `export`:

```
declare -x LANG="es_ES.ISO-8859-1"
declare -x LANGUAGE="es:en"
declare -x LC_ADDRESS="ms_MY.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_IDENTIFICATION="ms_MY.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_MEASUREMENT="ms_MY.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_MONETARY="ms_MY.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_NAME="ms_MY.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_NUMERIC="ms_MY.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_PAPER="ms_MY.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_TELEPHONE="ms_MY.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_TIME="ms_MY.UTF-8"
```

I am Spanish living in Malaysia, so I actually want my system in Spanish but with the country setup for Malaysia. I actually don't know whether I have set it up right or not.

Now, I try to launch a recently installed application, git-gui (amongst some others), and I just get the following error message:

```
$ git-gui
We are sorry, command-not-found failed! Please send a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please attach the following info to the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.3.1 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:        13.04
Codename:       raring
Exception information:

unsupported locale setting
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 24 in crash_guard
    callback()
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 69, in main
    enable_i18n()
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 40, in enable_i18n
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/locale.py", line 541, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

So **how can I fix my locales?** What would be the right setup for my system to match my requirements and also the requirements of applications such as `git-gui`?

Comment: To make it easier to help you, can you please add the output of the command `locale -a`

Comment: $ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
es_AR.utf8
es_BO.utf8
es_CL.utf8
es_CO.utf8
es_CR.utf8
es_DO.utf8
es_EC.utf8
es_ES.utf8
es_GT.utf8
es_HN.utf8
es_MX.utf8
es_NI.utf8
es_PA.utf8
es_PE.utf8
es_PR.utf8
es_PY.utf8
es_SV.utf8
es_US.utf8
es_UY.utf8
es_VE.utf8
ms_MY.utf8
POSIX

Answer (score 0):

There is no latin1 locale generated on your system, but still you have assigned LANG such a locale name. You should edit `/etc/default/locale`. I suppose that it - for some reason - contains the line

`LANG=es_ES.ISO-8859-1`

Change that line to

`LANG=es_ES.UTF-8`

and reboot.